# Local branch on top remote

Tags: git, version-control, github

I a have a local branch called ABC. I would like to add all these changes on top the remote branch develop. I guess this is done with a merge. I have been searching and found out how to push my branch to the origin but how do I merge it on top of my already existing remote branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the remote branch is called `develop` and you don't have any other `develop` branches:

```
git checkout develop
git merge ABC
# probably resolve conflicts and git commit
git push
```

Comment: Ok så changing your branch is the way to got. Thanks. The changes is there but also got this according to the master branch.! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:comapny/Repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration
hint: variable to 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.

Comment: I don't know what do you have and what do you want. Maybe you need push to a different branch, then just specify it `git push origin develop`. And don't forget `git pull...` in case if somebody else pushed something into the remote. Give more info then. List all branches `git branch -a` and explain what and where do you want to merge and push.